# What if the 'or' is exclusive instead of inclusive?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, optimization, mathematical-modeling, constraints

The context is an integer programming problem on choosing projects to maximise profit.

I think **(b) i.** changes if 'either project 1 or project 3' means 'project 1 *xor* project 3' rather than 'project 1 *or* project 3'

---

[image]

---

**What I tried:**

Let $x_i =$

$1$, if project i is selected and $0$, otherwise.

and

$c_{ij}$ be the expenditure in project i in year j

Obj func: Max

$$z = r \cdot x - \sum_{i} x_ic_{i1} - \sum_{i} x_ic_{i2} - \sum_{i} x_ic_{i3}$$

where

$r_i$ is the return of project i

$$r' = [10, 40, 20, 15, 30]$$

$$x' = [x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4, x_5]$$

s.t.

$$\sum_{i} x_{i}c_{i1} \le 25$$

$$\sum_{i} x_{i}c_{i2} \le 25$$

$$\sum_{i} x_{i}c_{i3} \le 25$$

---

bii

$$x_2 + x_4 \le 1$$

---

bi

**if either-or means or** (inclusive or):

$$x_4 \ge x_1, x_4 \ge x_3$$

**if either-or means xor** (exclusive or):

$$x_4 \ge x_1 + x_3 - y$$

where $y=2$ if $x_1 = x_3 = 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

---

Is that right?

---

From Chapter 3 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: There is no guaranteed correct answer for this, as natural language is inherently ambiguous. However, I would interpret this as being inclusive-or.

Comment: @mrp Thanks ^-^ So what's the answer if it's inclusive or? What's the answer if it's exclusive or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **inclusive or**:

$$x_4 \ge x_1 \ \text{and} \ x_4 \ge x_3$$

For **exclusive or**:

$$x_3 + x_4 \ge x_1 \ \text{and} \ x_1 + x_4 \ge x_3$$

---

Proofs based on [this](https://www.or-exchange.org/revisions/13477/):

For **inclusive or**:

$$(x_1 \bigvee x_3) \rightarrow x_4$$

$$\iff \neg (x_1 \bigvee x_3) \vee x_4$$

$$\iff (\neg x_1 \bigwedge \neg x_3) \vee x_4$$

$$\iff (\neg x_1 \vee x_4) \bigwedge (\neg x_3 \vee x_4) $$

$$\iff (1-x_1) + x_4 \ge 1 \ \text{and} \ (1-x_3) + x_4 \ge 1$$

$$\iff x_4 \ge x_1 \ \text{and} \ x_4 \ge x_3$$

For **exclusive or**:

$$(x_1 \bigvee x_3) \bigwedge \neg (x_1 \bigwedge x_3) \rightarrow x_4$$

[$$\iff (x_1 \bigwedge \neg x_3) \bigvee (x_3 \bigwedge \neg x_1 ) \rightarrow x_4$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalencies.2C_elimination.2C_and_introduction)

$$\vdots$$

$$(\neg x_1 \bigvee x_3 \bigvee x_4) \bigwedge (\neg x_3 \bigvee x_1 \bigvee x_4)$$

$$(1 - x_1) + x_3 + x_4 \ge 1 \ \text{and} \ (1 - x_3) + x_1 + x_4 \ge 1$$

$$x_3 + x_4 \ge x_1 \ \text{and} \ x_1 + x_4 \ge x_3$$

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments English is ambiguous. However, the standard has evolved that "or" **always** means inclusive or. It never means exclusive or.

Again, this is a convention of English language that's widely but not universally used, but is always my first assumption.

Comment: My question is not (anymore) what either-or means. My question is if the constraints are correct under each interpretation